# How to count the number of columns having specific value (lke '1') in PHPMyadmin DB table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below having 3 columns with value '1' or '0'.

```
S.no   Product    Qty1    Qty2    Qty3  
1.     Soap         1      0       1
2.     Ball         1      1       0
3.     Deodrant     0      0       0
4.     Butter       1      0       1
```

How can I count the total number of '1' in the table like the above in is having 6 nos? Also what if I want to count total rows having only '1' value?

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
 include 'Config.php';

 $conn = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 if ($conn->connect_error) 
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

// $sql = "SELECT SUM(Qty1 + Qty2 + Qty3) from Table"; doesn't seems to work


 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  echo $rowcount;
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  } 

 else
  echo "0";
}

 else
  echo "failed";

 $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: in you case just use `SUM`...

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: Complete statement if you can post? @AntonyJack

Comment: 'want to count total rows having only '1' value' - is ambiguous, do you mean rows where all the values are ones or rows where where there is only one 1 value?

Comment: I mean total number of columns with 1 value and also total rows having value as 1 in any column.

Comment: put your table details correctly... what is sw1 ???

Comment: Sry my bad. Its Qty1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select 
  sum(Qty1 + Qty2 + Qty3) total_ones,
  sum(Qty1 and Qty2 and Qty3) total_rows_with_ones
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gYGaASbpvUBbyUZF8fhPM5/0).
Results:

```
| total_ones | total_rows_with_ones |
| ---------- | -------------------- |
| 6          | 0                    |
```

Comment: As you can see in the demo the code in my answer works as expected.

Comment: @HoshangS your code returns the number of rows of the query which is always 1. You should return the value of the column returned.

Comment: Thanks got it now. But just for knowledge purpose what if I were to count total columns with value as 'good'? In that case, SUM won't work, right!

Comment: You can use SUM() like this: `sum((column1 = 'good') + (column2 = 'good') + (column3 = 'good'))`

Answer (score 1):

Hope its helpful...

```
SELECT
  sum(Qty1) as sum_Qty1
  , sum(Qty2) as sum_Qty2
  , sum(Qty3) as sum_Qty3
  , sum(Qty1) + sum(Qty2) + sum(Qty3) as tot_Qty 
FROM
  product
```

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation  sum(case when...

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(Sno int,   Product varchar(10),   Qty1 int,    Qty2 int,    Qty3 int);
insert into t values  
(1  ,   'Soap'       ,  1   ,   0    ,   1),
(2  ,   'Ball'       ,  1   ,   1    ,   0),
(3  ,   'Deodrant'   ,  0   ,   0    ,   0),
(4  ,   'Butter'     ,  1   ,   0    ,   1);


select 
  sum(Qty1 + Qty2 + Qty3) total_ones,
  sum(case when Qty1 = 1 or Qty2 = 1 or Qty3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) total_rows_with_ones
from t  ;


+------------+----------------------+
| total_ones | total_rows_with_ones |
+------------+----------------------+
|          6 |                    3 |
+------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```